# Null Pointer Exception in LinkedList Hash Table

Tags: java, pointers, hash, null, linked-list

So I'm creating a hash table with LinkedLists using the multiplication method. As an instance variable I define the LinkedList "`T`" that I'll be using, and in the constructor of the class I specify the size of T. However, every time I run my Driver testing class, I get NullPointerExceptions on everything I try to reference *anything* in `T[]`. Am I overlooking something? I've spent over an hour trying to figure it out.

**ChainedHashTable class:**

```java
public class ChainedHashTable
{
    private LinkedList<Integer>[] T;
    private int m;
    private double A;

    public ChainedHashTable(int n)
    {
        for (m = 1; m < n; m *= 2);
        T = new LinkedList[m];
        Random random = new Random();
        int s = random.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        A = (s * 1.00) / Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }

    public void insert(Integer key)
    {
        T[hash(key)].add(Integer.valueOf(key));
    }

    public void delete(int key)
    {
        T[hash(key)].remove(Integer.valueOf(key));
    }

    public Integer search(int key)
    {
        int n = T[hash(key)].indexOf(key);
        if (n == -1)
            return -1;
        else
            return T[hash(key)].get(n);
    }

    private int hash(int key)
    {
        System.out.println((int)(m * ((key * A) % 1)));
        return (int)(m * ((key * A) % 1));
    }

    public void printTable()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < T.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("index: " + i + " " + T[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Driver class:**

```java
public class Driver
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ChainedHashTable test1 = new ChainedHashTable(20);
        test1.printTable();
        test1.insert(4);
        test1.insert(54);
        test1.insert(6);
        test1.insert(3);
        test1.insert(26);
        test1.insert(54);
        test1.insert(11);
        test1.insert(10);
        test1.insert(76);
        test1.insert(42);
        test1.insert(41);
        test1.insert(32);
        test1.insert(87);
        test1.insert(76);
        test1.insert(72);
        test1.insert(57);
        test1.insert(29);
        test1.insert(16);
        test1.insert(92);
        test1.insert(64);
        test1.printTable();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating an **array of references** to type `LinkedList` and setting them to their initial state, which is `null`.

```
T = new LinkedList[m];
```

`T` now is an array of the computed size `m`. You need to initialize the objects inside of the array.

```
T = new LinkedList[m];
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    T[i] = new LinkedList<>();
}
```